# How to create a single query across associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `user` model that has one `profile` and also has one `goal`. The `profile` has a privacy field which is of type hstore, and in that field there can be a hash that indicates that it is OK to publicly display the `goal`, the hash looks like { 'show_goals' => '1' } if the `goal` can be displayed. I want a list of all goals that can be displayed publicly.  My initial attempt was

```
   def list_public
      profiles = Profile.includes(:user).where("privacy @> hstore('show_goals','1')")
      goals = []
      profiles.each do |p|
        goals << p.user.goals.first
      end
      goals
    end
  end
```

This works fine when there was a small number of users opting into allow their goals to be displayed, but is clearly not scaleable.  Is there a single or a couple of `ActiveRecord` sql queries that can do the job of this code? I am using `ruby on rails 5.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to also eager load the `goals` in your query:

```
profiles = Profile.includes(:user, user: :goals).where("privacy @> hstore('show_goals','1')")
```

This will produce one additional query fetching all the goals. You can then still use the remaining code as is, `p.user.goals.first` will not generate an additional database query.